# Problema no carregamento do .css comprimido no IE9

Tags: php, css3, internet-explorer-9

Estou com um problema de carregamento de estilos de uma página exclusivamente no IE9, nos outros navegadores e versões IE10-11 funcionam corretamente. A página utiliza o Bootstrap 3.1 e outro template, assim que utiliza vários arquivos `.css`. Estes arquivos estão sendo comprimidos por conta de otimização, no entanto ao carregar a página só os arquivos `.css` do Bootstrap é que estão sendo carregados.

Compartilho parte do código onde é carregado o `.css`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <?php
    foreach($view->_css as $css){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css.'">'."\n";
    }
    foreach($view->_js as $js){
        echo '<script src="'.$js.'"></script>'."\n";
    }
    ?>
    <title>Alfa</title>
```

Qual a solução?